# Loop playFile discord.js

Tags: node.js, typescript, discord.js

New to Typescript/JS/D.JS looking to make a Discord bot loop the playFile method indefinitely. Here's what I've got so far but I think the issue is that its trying to play it multiple times at once.

```
msgObject.member.voiceChannel.join()
    .then(connection => {
        function play(){
            const dispatcher = connection.playFile('./audio.wav');
        }
        while(msgObject.guild.me.speaking === false) {
            play();
        }
    })
    .catch(console.error);
```

Want to make this just play over and over until I stop it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `dispatcher` is instance of `StreamDispatcher`. According to the [`doc`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/StreamDispatcher?scrollTo=e-end) there are events fired.
So, you can add the end listner,

```
const dispatcher = connection.playFile('./audio.wav');
dispatcher.on('end', function(){
    //do some conditionals and SEEK it to 0   
})
```

Comment: msgObject.member.voiceChannel.join()
        .then(connection => {
          const dispatcher = connection.playFile('../dist/atis.wav');
          dispatcher.on('end', function(){
            const dispatcher = connection.playFile('../dist/atis.wav');
        })  


Simply plays it once more afterwards. Looking to make it loop forever. What am I missing?

Comment: Hey it seems when I do this the audio is noticeably laggy, any tips?

Comment: You should destroy the current dispatcher. And create a new dispatcher